# Discrete Math logically equivalent?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Show that 
$$(p \land q) \lor (\lnot p \land \lnot q) \equiv p\leftrightarrow q$$

How would I go about doing this?

Do I use a truth table or a more "algebraic" process?

Comment: You could use a truth table. Equivalence means the statement $(p \leftrightarrow q) \leftrightarrow [(p \land q) \lor (\neg p \land \neg q)]$ is a tautology.

Comment: How would I set it up, though? we've only gone over simple truth tables in class, with just p, q, and simple conditional statements. Is there a way to prove this without using a truth table?

Comment: What do you mean? You'd set it up just like any other truth table - work from the inside outwards towards the full proposition.

Answer (score 2):

$$(p \land q) \lor (\lnot p \land \lnot q)$$
$$\equiv(p \lor (\lnot p \land \lnot q)) \land (q\lor(\lnot p \land \lnot q))$$
$$\equiv(p \lor \lnot p) \land(p\lor \lnot q)\land (q\lor\lnot p)\land (q\lor\lnot q)$$
$$\equiv(p\lor \lnot q)\land (q\lor\lnot p)$$
$$\equiv(\lnot q\lor p)\land (\lnot p\lor q)$$
$$\equiv (p\to q)\land(q\to p)$$
$$\equiv p\leftrightarrow q$$

Answer (score 0):

Well, a more reasoning process is acceptable. Here is how I would prove it:

Suppose $p\equiv q$ then $p\leftrightarrow  q \equiv \mathbb T$ not matter what the value of $q$ and $p$ is. Now if $q \equiv \neg p$ or vice versa, then $p \leftrightarrow q \equiv \mathbb F$. So if the value is the same, the statement is true. Otherwise it's false. This english interpretation is clearly the same as $(p\wedge q) \vee (\neg p \wedge \neg q)$.
$\square $

BTW, this is a squashed version of the cases proof, where you take the case $p\equiv q$ and show that the statements are equivalent and then take the case $p \equiv \neg q$ and repeat the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a truth table or the below, and rather lengthy, series of logical equivalences:

---

$$(p↔q)≡[(p∧q)∨(¬p∧¬q)]$$

---

$$(p∧q)∨(¬p∧¬q)$$

$$≡[(p∧q)∨¬p]∧[(p∧q)∨¬q]$$

$$≡[(p∨¬p)∧(q∨¬p)]∧[(p∧q)∨¬q]$$

$$≡[(p∨¬p)∧(q∨¬p)]∧[(p∨¬q)∧(q∨¬q)]$$

$$≡[TRUE∧(q∨¬p)]∧[(p∨¬q)∧(q∨¬q)]$$

$$≡(q∨¬p)∧[(p∨¬q)∧(q∨¬q)]$$

$$≡(q∨¬p)∧[(p∨¬q)∧TRUE]$$

$$≡(q∨¬p)∧(p∨¬q)$$

$$≡(¬p∨q)∧(p∨¬q)$$

$$≡(p→q)∧(p∨¬q)$$

$$≡(p→q)∧(¬q∨p)$$

$$≡(p→q)∧(q→p)$$

$$≡(p↔q)$$

$$□$$

Or

$$(p↔q)$$

$$≡(p→q)∧(q→p)$$

$$≡(¬p∨q)∧(q→p)$$

$$≡(¬p∨q)∧(¬q∨p)$$

$$≡[(¬p∨q)∧¬q]∨[(¬p∨q)∧p]$$

$$≡[(¬p∧¬q)∨(q∧¬q)]∨[(¬p∨q)∧p]$$

$$≡[(¬p∧¬q)∨FALSE]∨[(¬p∨q)∧p]$$

$$≡(¬p∧¬q)∨[(¬p∨q)∧p]$$

$$≡(¬p∧¬q)∨[(¬p∧p)∨(q∧p)]$$

$$≡(¬p∧¬q)∨[FALSE∨(q∧p)]$$

$$≡(¬p∧¬q)∨(q∧p)$$

$$≡(q∧p)∨(¬p∧¬q)$$

$$≡(p∧q)∨(¬p∧¬q)$$

$$□$$